# how to update all tables with a particular column name

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am trying to update all tables starting with string like 'agg%' and column_name ='%userid%'...
But i dont see any such examples online even though i was able to find option to select all tables with a particular column name and table name I need to do the same to update those tables something like this :

```
    update TABLE_NAME set COLUMN_NAME='rajeev' WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%userid%'
and TABLE_NAME LIKE 'agg%'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;
```

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*To get the update query for your condition*

```
     select 
        'update '||c.table_name||' set '||c.COLUMN_NAME||' = ''rajeev'';' 
         as my_update_query
     from 
        (select 
            table_name,COLUMN_NAME
         from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
         where table_name LIKE 'agg%' and COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%userid%') c
```

---

*To execute*

```
 do $$
  declare
    arow record;
  begin
    for arow in
    select 
        'update '||c.table_name||' set '||c.COLUMN_NAME||' = ''rajeev'';' 
         as my_update_query
     from 
        (select 
            table_name,COLUMN_NAME
         from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
         where table_name LIKE 'agg%' and COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%userid%') c
    loop
     execute arow.my_update_query;
    end loop;
  end;
$$;
```

Comment: @user3393089 or put the above into a PL/pgSQL block and use dynamic SQL. There are plenty of examples on SO that show how to do that.

Comment: please help me! How to execute this with node-postgres? I am really suffering for 10 hours with this