# SQL Select rows and delete/update from dynamic multiple tables

Tags: sql

I need some help with an sql statemen.
I have different schemas and same table names.
With the following select i can get all the tables:

```
select name from sys.tables where QUOTENAME(name) = '[Table_1]'
```

Now i want to loop through all the tables, and have some similar query to this:

```
delete from tablename where condition1 > condition2
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: you probably need something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25780596/3682599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
declare @count int, @i  int = 1, @sql nvarchar(max), @tablename varchar(1000)

select @count = count(*) from sys.tables where QUOTENAME(name) = '[Table_1]'

create table #temp(id int identity(1,1), table varchar(1000))
insert into #temp
select name from sys.tables where QUOTENAME(name) = '[Table_1]'

while(@i<=@count)
begin
   select @tablename = (select table from #temp where id = @i)
   set @sql = 'delete from '+@tablename+' where condition1>condition2'
   execute sp_executesql @sql
   set @i = @i+1
end
```

Comment: First error was, 
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table'.
So i changed table to tbl
Second error was:
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid column name 'name'.

Comment: After that i have Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid column name 'name'. at the line (select name from #temp where id = @i)

Comment: after modification, this is the error:

Here is the error:
Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_execute, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@handle' of type 'int'.
Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_execute, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@handle' of type 'int'.

Comment: modified line is:

select QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id))+'.'+QUOTENAME(name) from sys.tables where QUOTENAME(name) = '[Table_1]'

Comment: No probs with your modification try above query now

Comment: It doesnt work. I changed set @sql = 'delete from '+@tablename+'where Id = 1' and i have:
 Incorrect syntax near 'Id'.