# Sql Server: update every 'null' string record in database

Tags: sql-server, null

I have made a mistake in migrating data to my new sql server database: almost every record that should be null has now a 'null' string value in it.

Is there a reasonably quick way to update the entire database and substitute each 'null' record with a real null?

I am trying with something like this:

```
 SELECT ' update ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + 'set value = null 
 where value = 'NULL''
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

but I'm looking for some advice on how to iterate over each column in each table.

Comment: If this is a new database it would probably be easier to simply drop the database and import fresh, after fixing the process of course. This was of course on your test system right??

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780297/how-to-update-all-tables-with-a-particular-column-name

Comment: @PrabhatG this is tagged with sql server. The duplicate you suggested is postgre, they are not the same thing.

Comment: I'd prefer not to drop the database because i have imported data from db2   using bulk insert which was quite a long process; I tryed also automated data migration with ssma but it didn't work correctly

Comment: Well doing an update for every column in every table is going to be a long process too. It is going to take time to write and it is going to be super slow.

Comment: Note that in TSQL, to get single quotes in your variable that you need to escape them with a single quote.  F.e. `set @v = '... where value=''NULL'';';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a query to create sql for you. Something like this. If you need to handle text and ntext you will have to look up their type_id values in sys.types. I didn't include them since they should be being used in the first place.

```
select 'update ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + quotename(t.name) + 
    ' set ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' = NULL where '
    + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' = ''NULL'''
from sys.tables t
join sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id
join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
where c.system_type_id in
(
    167 --varchar
    , 175 --char
    , 231 --nvarchar
    , 239 --nchar
)
```

Comment: getting inspiration from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780297/how-to-update-all-tables-with-a-particular-column-name I came up with this:` SELECT ' update ' + table_schema + '.' +table_name + ' set '+ COLUMN_NAME +' = null where '+ COLUMN_NAME + '= ''NULL'''
FROM(        select 
            table_schema,table_name,COLUMN_NAME
         from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where DATA_TYPE = 'varchar') c `, are there difference with your answer?

Comment: @Argentina it will only update varchar columns, not char, nchar and nvarchar columns. Also views are included in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.

Comment: Aside from the difference that your code will only update varchar you may or may not get the schema correct. The INFORMATION_SCHEMA views are not always reliable. Notice even the documentation suggests you shouldn't use it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql

Answer (score 1):

You can run the query below during the night. It will make an update statement for each string type column, than execute all the statements.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''

select @sql = @sql + 'update '+ t.name + ' set '+ c.name + ' = null where '+ c.name + '=''null''' +char(13) + char(10)
from sys.tables t
join sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
join sys.types ty on c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
where ty.name like '%char'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```